# use laravel Authentication in pure php scripts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am working on a laravel App. a part of that is written pure php that is a html form and form submission script that stores data to Database.

Suppose `form.php` page is like :

```
<?php
    require('config.php');
?> 
<form action="process.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="username">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And `process.php` page is :

```
<?php
require ('config.php');
?> 
if (isset($_POST['submit_edu'])) {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        // other codes to store data to DB
}
```

Now I want just Authenticated Users in main laravel app can access to those pages and send their info.

To access `Auth` laravel Object, I added below codes to beginning of `config.php` file that holds connection settings and required by those two page:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
    $app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
    $kernel   = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );

    if (!Auth::check()) {
        exit('Only authorized Users can access to this page');
    }
```

As you can see if an unAuthorized user want to pages Encounters an error.

Now when an Authenticated user want to open `form.php` page (in face via `GET` method) `Auth::check()` works correctly but when clicks on submit form button and data sent to `process.php` (via `POST` method) , it always returns `false`.

While if I open same `process.php` via `GET` method  `Auth::check()` works correctly again.

Means in this case `Auth::check()` can not work properly.

What is problem in your idea. can anyone help me to solve this problem?

**Update :**

Even I used `EventServiceProvider` and authentication events to create a session. first I added this to provider :

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
    'App\Listeners\SessionLoginEnable',
 ],
```

And in `SessionLoginEnable`:

```
public function handle (Login $event)
        {
            session(['user_is_logged_in' => true]);
        }
```

then I added:

```
 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
            'App\Listeners\SessionLoginDisable',
        ],
```

And in that :

```
public function handle (Logout $event)
        {
            session(['user_is_logged_in' => false]);
        }
```

And in the other hand to check and user created session first I tried in `config.php` :

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
    $app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
    $kernel   = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );

    $is_logged  =   session('user_is_logged_in');*

if ( !is_logged  ) {
        exit('Only authorized Users can access to this page');
    }
```

This solution did not work.

Then I tried this :

```
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['user_is_logged_in']) or $_SESSION['user_is_logged_in'] != true) {
    exit('Only authorized Users can access to this page');
}
```

But in this case again, the answer not receive and It seems `$_SESSION['user_is_logged_in']` could not be recognized.

Another solution remains?

Comment: Why? Just build that page in the framework and you'll have access to everything Laravel offers. It makes no sense to do what you are doing.

Comment: form that I provided in fact is part of a large form with a lot of elements that is written by Someone else in html and pure php and I have to use as a part of a my laravel app. and I do not want to recreate it and if can limit access to those for laravel authorized users all things is done.